# Array within an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-grid

I have an example of displaying an array of values in a grid. It currently works fine. I'm using the following template to display the description for each Territory:

```
<script type="text/kendo" id="territoriesTemplate">
<ul>
    #for(var i = 0; i < Territories.length; i++){#
        <li>#:Territories[i].TerritoryName#</li>
    #}#
</ul>
</script>
```

This function is to serialize the array from the `territories` JSON datasource:

```
var territories = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["territories"])));

function serializeArray(prefix, array, result) {
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ($.isPlainObject(array[i])) {
        for (var property in array[i]) {
            result[prefix + "[" + i + "]." + property] = array[i][property];
        }
    }
    else {
        result[prefix + "[" + i + "]"] = array[i];
    }
  } 
}
```

Each Employee belongs to multiple Territories. Likewise, each Territory belongs to multiple Regions. I'm trying to display Employees, Territories and their associated Regions in a single grid.

I'm sure the `serializeArray` function will need to be modified, but I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried the following template but I'm guessing its incorrect:

```
<script type="text/kendo" id="territoriesTemplate">
<ul>
    #for(var i = 0; i < Territories.length; i++){#
        <li>#:Territories[i].Regions#</li>
    #}#
</ul>
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Using JSON for it. You can manipulate it easily and you can find the data from your array more easily.

Comment: I am using JSON together with some ViewData fields to load the array data.